# Как построить Sql Запрос что бы получить данные из таблицы в одну строку

Tags: php, mysql, sql

есть таблица `worker` (работник) с данными — id (id работника), first_name (имя), last_name
(фамилия)
таблица `child` (ребенок) с данными — worker_id (id работника), name (имя ребенка)
таблица `car` (машина) с данными — worker_id (id работника), model (модель машины)

Есть запрос:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM worker INNER JOIN car ON worker.id = car.user_id INNER JOIN child ON worker.id = child.user_id";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$worker = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($worker);

на выходе получаю :
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => Алексей
            [last_name] => Бирюзуцкий
            [user_id] => 1
            [model] => Lada
            [name] => Кирилл
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [first_name] => Алексей
        [last_name] => Бирюзуцкий
        [user_id] => 1
        [model] => Lada
        [name] => Алина
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [first_name] => Константин
        [last_name] => Коновалов
        [user_id] => 2
        [model] => Mazda
        [name] => Дима
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [first_name] => Константин
        [last_name] => Коновалов
        [user_id] => 2
        [model] => Mazda
        [name] => Костя
    )
```

а Нужно :

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => Алексей
            [last_name] => Бирюзуцкий
            [user_id] => 1
            [model] => Lada
            [name] => Кирилл,Алина
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [first_name] => Константин
            [last_name] => Коновалов
            [user_id] => 2
            [model] => Mazda
            [name] => Дима, Костя
        )

Comment: Если у  одного работника будет 2 ребенка и три машины вы получите 6 записей! И 'child (ребенок) с данными — worker_id (id работника)' не совпадает по полю связи в запросе JOIN child ON worker.id = child.user_id

Answer (score 0):

Исходный массив (измененный, для усложнения задачи):

```
$workers = [
    [
        'id'            => 1,
        'first_name'    => 'Алексей',
        'last_name'     => 'Бирюзуцкий',
        'user_id'       => 1,
        'model'         => 'Lada',
        'name'          => 'Кирилл'
    ],
    [
        'id'            => 1,
        'first_name'    => 'Алексей',
        'last_name'     => 'Бирюзуцкий',
        'user_id'       => 1,
        'model'         => 'Lada',
        'name'          => 'Алина'
    ],
    [
        'id'            => 2,
        'first_name'    => 'Константин',
        'last_name'     => 'Коновалов',
        'user_id'       => 2,
        'model'         => 'Mazda',
        'name'          => 'Дима'
    ],
    [
        'id'            => 2,
        'first_name'    => 'Константин',
        'last_name'     => 'Коновалов',
        'user_id'       => 2,
        'model'         => 'Mazda',
        'name'          => 'Костя'
    ],
    [
        'id'            => 2,
        'first_name'    => 'Константин',
        'last_name'     => 'Коновалов',
        'user_id'       => 2,
        'model'         => 'Mazda',
        'name'          => 'Аня'
    ],
    [
        'id'            => 2,
        'first_name'    => 'Константин',
        'last_name'     => 'Коновалов',
        'user_id'       => 2,
        'model'         => 'Mazda',
        'name'          => 'Маша'
    ],
];
```

Решение:

```
foreach ($workers as $worker1) {
    foreach ($workers as $worker2) {
        if ($worker1['id'] == $worker2['id']) {
            $tmpWorkers[$worker2['id']]['names'][$worker2['name']]  = $worker2['name'];
            $tmpWorkers[$worker2['id']]['data']                     = array_merge($worker1, $worker2);

            $name = array_diff($worker1, $worker2)['name'];

            if ($name) {
                $tmpWorkers[$worker2['id']]['names'][$name] = $name;
                $tmpWorkers[$worker2['id']]['data']         = array_merge($worker1, $worker2);
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach ($tmpWorkers as $id => $value) {
    $resultWorkers[$id]         = $value['data'];
    $resultWorkers[$id]['name'] = implode(',', $value['names']);
}
```

Вывод:

```
print_r($resultWorkers);

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => Алексей
            [last_name] => Бирюзуцкий
            [user_id] => 1
            [model] => Lada
            [name] => Кирилл,Алина
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [first_name] => Константин
            [last_name] => Коновалов
            [user_id] => 2
            [model] => Mazda
            [name] => Дима,Костя,Аня,Маша
        )

)
```

---

Не самое лакончиное решение конечно, прошу сильно не бить, но задачу решает.